# Can I use variable for hosts in Ansible template?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to substitute hosts: target with variable?

```
- name: ansible application deploy
  hosts: {{ vm_ip }}
  vars:
    project_path: "{{ host_project_path|default('/var/www/html') }}"
```

I have tried passing vm_ip using `--extra-vars="vm_ip: IPP_ADDR "` on the command line, but it never worked.

Comment: I can't imagine a need for that. Could you explain why you need this? There is a lot of ways to do this without using a variable on hosts.

Comment: I'm developing rails application that would execute ansible scripts to automate few things in the backend, and script needs to run against different VMs based on the task, can you think of any idea on how I would go about replacing hosts value? I was thinking about running sed or awk first then run the script, but using variable would be cleaner

Comment: Why don't set hosts: all, or set to a group that contains all VMs of that application and just execute the playbook with -l vm_ip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather just set `hosts:all` and execute the playbook with `limit` to only the host you need to execute.

```
- name: ansible application deploy
  hosts: all
  vars:
    project_path: "{{ host_project_path|default('/var/www/html') }}"
```

Execute the playbook using the `limit` clause:

`ansible-playbook app_deploy.yml -l IPP_ADDR`

Another possibilite is creating a file with the ip address.

`/tmp/execute_only_that_host`

**FILE CONTENT:**

`IPP_ADDR`

Executing: `ansible-playbook app_deploy.yml -l @/tmp/execute_only_that_host`

I recommend this approach because it's your own application that will call your playbook, you can always insure it called with `limit`, therefore you don't need to bother with `hosts` in the top of your playbook.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `limit`, if you forget to specify that by mistake, then it will run on all hosts which is dangerous. Your command line is wrong. Try:

```
--extra-vars "vm_ip=IP_ADDR"
```

and

```
hosts: "{{ vm_ip }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it from the command line, yes.

Make sure you have valid yaml:

```
hosts: "{{ vm_ip }}"
```

That expression has to be quoted or you run into the [yaml gotcha](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#hey-wait-a-yaml-gotcha).

But the hosts have to be defined in the inventory first and I guess this is the piece you're missing. That pretty much makes it pointless as there is no advantage over using `hosts: all` with a `--limit` as described by @Bernardo Vale - but is more ansible standard.